# How does one tell yum to ignore a repo file with a parsing error?

Tags: rpm, yum

I have a webserver where I can install things using yum but do not have access to the /etc/yum.repos.d directory, rpm, nor yum-config-manager. I installed an rpm that added a repository but it has parsing error in it. Is there a way to tell yum to ignore that file (or all files) in order to remove the item that added it (thus removing the .repo file with the parsing error)?

OS: RHEL7

I've tried disabling the repo, disabling all repos, using -t to be fault tolerant, and -C to run from cache only. Still get parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Figured a waybout:

- copied the `/etc/yum.conf` and `/etc/yum.repos.d/` to a local directory
- fixed issue in the copied `.repo` file
- updated the copied `yum.conf` `repodir` key to point at copied directory
- ran yum using `sudo yum --config ./yum.conf remove <bad>.rpm`